# Filter data while reading it from SQL server based on prior dataframe value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter

I have two massive tables that are on Azure SQL servers that I am trying to get into my notebook. The first table is filtered on date, but to filter the second table, I need to find the minimum of the primary key of the second table, and import it. Basically this is what I am trying:

```
val date = "make_date(2023,06,01)"

val TableA= spark.read.synapsesql("sqlserver.dbo.table1")
.select("columnA"
,"columnB"
,"DateColumn")
.toDF()
.filter(expr("DateColumn>="+date))
.repartition(20)
.createOrReplaceTempView("TableA")


val min = spark.sql("""select min(columnA) as mincolA from TableA""".stripMargin)



val TableB = spark.read.synapsesql("sqlserver.dbo.tableB")
.select("columnA"
,"columnC")
.filter(expr("columnA >="+min))
```

This is giving me the following error when trying to filter:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
===SQL===

columnA >= [min: bigint]
```

How can i fix this? Any help is much appreciated! I don't want to pull in a billion records if it can be avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In provided code, type of `val min` is Dataframe (not a date). For get date, `getAs[Date]` can be used:

```
val min = spark.sql("""select min(columnA) as mincolA from TableA""".stripMargin)
.first().getAs[Date]("mincolA")
```

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified. the second value should be an integer, not a date.

Comment: @SarbajitChakraborty if min is integer, ".getAs[Int]" can be used instead of ".getAs[Date]".